# Security: How to validate image file uploads?

Tags: php, image, security, upload, mime-types

I need to accept image file uploads from the users.

How can I check and be 100% sure that I don't get a malicious file or something?

Check the mime type? Re-draw the image? Anti-virus?

Comment: Depends. And I wouldn’t go for 100 %. You probably can’t. Only maximize.

Comment: One thing you should be aware of is that even if it's an innocuous image, it can also be something else.  http://www.thinkfu.com/blog/gifjavascript-polyglots shows how to construct a valid GIF that is also a malicious JavaScript file.

Answer (score 8):

Redraw the image, read it up with [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php)'s `imagecreatefromXXX()` and save it back with `imageXXX()`

This way you can also scale it to more convenient sizes and keep bandwidth consumption in check.

To save on computing power, deny upload to files bigger than a certain limit.

5megs or 10megs should be fine, as limits go.

Keep GD updated, and be wary that (7 years ago, apparently) *[it used to sport buffer overflows](http://www.net-security.org/advisory.php?id=4019)* in the handling of **PNG images**

> Alternatively, you could also preprocess uploaded images in background with commands such as [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)'s `convert` and such.
>
> Last note of warning: *on Windo(w)s* `convert` is also a command used to *format hard disk*, so put some effort into removing abiguities if you deploy on that.

Comment: ImageMagick was not written for this kind of thing : http://lwn.net/Articles/206928/ .  If you use ImageMagick on untrusted inputs, sandbox it.  Anything, VMWare, Linux-VServer, UML can help keep ImageMagick away from the file system and privileged processor modes so if it's compromised, the only thing that's compromised is a VM.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about malicious files use an antivirus checker, or better yet, two of them since one might be lagging on a particular new strain.

MIME types can be spoofed, as can using `file`.

You could use code to open it, checking to see if all the blocks are the right sizes, but exploits take advantage of flaws in the code used to open the image. You could be opening the door to exploit on your host/server if your code isn't hardened and aware of all the ways it could be exploited - it's almost a chicken and egg situation, so I lean toward trusting a couple antivirus tools more.

Answer (score 0):

I would not go for 100% image type validation, I use simple script to check image type validation

```
<?php

$imgExtension = array('jpg','jpe','jpeg','gif','png');
$image_name = pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name']);
$extension = strtolower($image_name['extension']);
if(in_array($extension,$ImgExtension)) {
    //process file upload - move_uploaded_file()
}

?>
```

Still you can also check mime type to make more accurate validation.

Comment: But this way I can just simply take a .exe, rename it to .jpg and would be able to deploy it via the server.

Answer (score -3):

I'm not sure if it's completely safe but you could use

```
if( getimagesize($filename) )
  //probably an image
```